# cycle through split, stacked, tabbed modes with single shortcut (and skip stacked mode, too)

Tags: i3

I somewhat find pressing `Alt+w`, `Alt+e` and `Alt+s` to use the different modes confusing due to the following reasons:

1. I fail to see the difference between the stacked and the tabbed mode (and would like to just use tabbed instead)
2. I can think of no obvious mnemonics.
3. I strain my fingers cycling between the three modes (especially when I keep forgetting which shortcut corresponds to which layout - due to the non-obvious mnemonics mentioned above).

I would like to define a **single** shortcut that would toggle between only the two of the three modes that I find relevant: tabbed and split (default). Can I accomplish that in the `config` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your config file:

```
bindsym $mod+Tab layout toggle tabbed split
```

and change $mod+Tab to your desired key combination.